# php Making first letter of a function result uppercase

Tags: php, uppercase

I have a function that returns me a word. I want this word to have the first letter uppercase.

```
$parts = array ("ing", "er", "a", "on", "po", "i", 
    "re", "tion", "con");


function getWord ($parts)  {
    //getting number of array elements
    $result = count($parts)-1;

    $x = mt_rand(0, $result);
    $y = mt_rand(0, $result);
    $z = mt_rand(0, $result);

     $oneSyl = $parts[$x];
     $twoSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y];
     $threeSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y].$parts[$z];

    //creating an array of 1,2,3 syllable words
     $newWord = array ($oneSyl, $twoSyl, $threeSyl);

    // getting a number from 0 to 2 
     $randLength = mt_rand(0, 2);

    echo $newWord[$randLength];

    }

getWord($parts);
```

I tried `ucfirst()`, but it needs a string value, an I only have a function.
How can I add `ucfirst()` to a function? or How can i get a word which first  character is uppercase

Thank you.

Comment: Your function doesn't return a word, it prints it. So you could use `echo ucfirst($newWord[$randLength]);`. If you use `return $newWord …;` you could use `echo ucfirst(getWord($parts));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you need to do this

```
echo ucfirst($newWord[$randLength]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = array ("ing", "er", "a", "on", "po", "i", 
    "re", "tion", "con");


function getWord ($parts)  {
    //getting number of array elements
    $result = count($parts)-1;

    $x = mt_rand(0, $result);
    $y = mt_rand(0, $result);
    $z = mt_rand(0, $result);

     $oneSyl = $parts[$x];
     $twoSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y];
     $threeSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y].$parts[$z];

    //creating an array of 1,2,3 syllable words
     $newWord = array ($oneSyl, $twoSyl, $threeSyl);

    // getting a number from 0 to 2 
     $randLength = mt_rand(0, 2);
//edited
    echo ucfirst($newWord[$randLength]);

    }

getWord($parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I get you.You can add a line as:

```
$parts = array ("ing", "er", "a", "on", "po", "i", 
"re", "tion", "con");


function getWord ($parts)  {
//getting number of array elements
$result = count($parts)-1;

$x = mt_rand(0, $result);
$y = mt_rand(0, $result);
$z = mt_rand(0, $result);

 $oneSyl = $parts[$x];
 $twoSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y];
 $threeSyl = $parts[$x].$parts[$y].$parts[$z];

//creating an array of 1,2,3 syllable words
 $newWord = array ($oneSyl, $twoSyl, $threeSyl);

// getting a number from 0 to 2 
 $randLength = mt_rand(0, 2);

//Here is the modified line
echo ucfirst($newWord[$randLength]);

}

getWord($parts);
```